# roots of an equation modulo m

Tags: roots

Proof, that the equation $$(x^2-13)(x^2-17)(x^2-13*17)$$ has no roots in $$\mathbb{Z}$$ but for every modulo $$m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$$.
It is obvious that the equation has no solutions in $$\mathbb{Z}$$.
I've already found out that the equation does have solutions modulo m for m=2,3,4.. and so on, but I am not sure how to prove it for every m.
Maybe someone can give me a small hint :)

Comment: It is obvious that the equation has no roots in $$\mathbb{Z}$$. I've already found out that the equation does have solutions modulo m for m=2, 3 and so on, but I have no idea how to prove it for every m.

Comment: Can you settle it for all prime moduli?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/947379). And [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Hint : What can you conclude if a prime is neither $13$ nor $17$ and neither a quadratic residue modulo $13$ nor modulo $17$ ?